# Extending functions from integers to reals. What properties (generally) matter?

Tags: continuity, interpolation, analytic-continuation

There's no shortage of functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$, or perhaps more generally $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$, which then later get defined over some continuum like $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ or $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(n)=f(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Although there is imaginably no formal way to do this "nicely" for all such functions $f(n)$, I'd like to compile a general list of properties that $g$ should obey.

Some classic examples of functions, $f$, and their extension, $g$, include
$$
\begin{align*}
f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}&\iff g(x)=\psi(x+1)+\gamma,\\
f(n)=n!&\iff g(x)=\Gamma(x+1),\\
f(n)=F_n &\iff g(x)=\frac{\phi^x-(-\phi)^x}{\sqrt{5}},
\end{align*}
$$
where $F_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibbonacci number, $\phi$ is the golden ratio, $\psi$ is the digamma function, and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

There are, of course, infinitely many other choices for $g$, given any $f$, but there is often an intuitive way to restrict ourselves to one which fulfils certain additional properties. Here are some general observations of properties of $g$ I've noticed.

- **Some functional equation:**
  For example, the fact that $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$ is carried over to the Gamma function, and for sums like $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n s_n$, we often have that $g(x+1)=g(x)+s_{x+1}$.
- **Continuity or differentiability:**
  Self explanatory, as probably the most important new properties allowed by extending the domain to a continuum.
- **Log-convexity:** For the example of the Gamma function, it is the only log-convex function over $\mathbb{R}$ which interpolates the factorials and obeys the same functional equation.
- **Holomorphism:** As with the Gamma function, again, it is effectively the only holomorphic function over on the positive complex half-plane which obeys the same functional equation and remains bounded for $1<\Re(x)<2$.

So my question(s) is/are

> What other properties have you noticed fulfilled by various functions $g$?

> When do we care about certain properties like continuity, differentiability, log-convexity or it being holomorphic?

> Is there some notion of a meta-algorithm for appending desired properties until we are sure there exists only one such extension?

Comment: Any function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ whose restriction to $\mathbb Z$ is $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ is an extension of $f$. There is no way to way to compile a general list of properties that $g$ should obey.

Comment: @KurtG. What you say, of course, is undeniably true and goes without saying. Yet do you know what I mean when I say that "there is often an intuitive way to restrict ourselves to one which fulfils certain additional properties? I am sure you know what I mean and have experienced this phenomenon too. There somehow feels like a canonical way to do this, transcendental to immediate reason. Occam's Razor?